# How to catch extraneous input in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I want to catch extraneous error in antlr4. It only prints to stderr something like

```
line 1:16 extraneous input 'three' expecting {<EOF>, PLUS_MINUS, MUL_DIV}
```

but doesn't throw any error.

Comment: I assume you need to make a pattern (term) to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANTLR lexer implements the [`ANTLRErrorListener`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.java) interface and initializes it to the `ConsoleErrorListener`.

In your code constructing the lexer, optionally remove the `ConsoleErrorListener` and add your own implementation, *i.e.*, `YourListener extends BaseErrorListener`.

Comment: You need to attach the listerner to *both* the Lexer and the Parser if you want to capture errors from both levels.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68810028/1331446 for a Python3 example.