# How to catch extraneous input in ANTLR4 in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, antlr4

Yes, this is nearly a duplicate of [How to catch extraneous input in ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879298/how-to-catch-extraneous-input-in-antlr4) - but that is in the case of Java, I need a solution for Python, and porting the Java solution is just not working for me!

ANTLR4 is writing the following "error" to the console.  I want this to result in a hard stop, but the parser continues and eventually re-syncs:

```
line 12:28 extraneous input 'FREDDY' expecting {'AS', ...
```

I want this to be a fatal error.

So, I've defined my own Error Listener, and overriden all 4 methods:

```
class MyErrorListener( ErrorListener ):

    __slots__ = [ 'file_name' ]
    
    def __init__(self, file_name="<stdin>"):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
        print(f"{self.file_name} {line}:{column} {msg[0:min(80,len(msg)-1)]}", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
        
    def reportAmbiguity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, exact, ambigAlts, configs):
        print(f"{self.file_name} {startIndex}-{stopIndex} reportAmbiguity {ambigAlts}", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    def reportAttemptingFullContext(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, conflictingAlts, configs):
        print(f"{self.file_name} {startIndex}-{stopIndex} conflictingAlts {conflictingAlts}", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    def reportContextSensitivity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, prediction, configs):
        print(f"{self.file_name} {startIndex}-{stopIndex} ContextSensitivity {prediction}", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I create my lexer, remove the default console error listener, and add mine in:

```py
        st = InputStream(upper_case)
        lexer:PlSqlLexer = PlSqlLexer(st)
        # Add your error listener to the lexer if required
        lexer.removeErrorListeners()
        lexer.addErrorListener( MyErrorListener(f) )
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser = PlSqlParser(stream)
        tree = parser.sql_script()
        printer = PlSqlPrintListener(txt)
        walker = ParseTreeWalker()
        walker.walk(printer, tree)
```

And this *is* catching some errors, such as:

```
sql_parser.py 1:0 token recognition error at: '"""\n
```

(That's me feeding a Python program into an SQL Parser - of course it shouldn't work!)

But my Error Listner isn't catching the error that I reported at the top.

Any suggestions?

- ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.9.2
- Python 3.7.3
- antlr4-python3-runtime v4.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution; both the Lexer and the Parser are "Recognizers".  The Recognizer is where the listener listens.

In consequence, we have two types of errors, Lexing errors and Parsing errors.  I was only attaching my listener to the Lexer, I needed to also attach it to the *Parser*.  Revised code:

```
        ...
        lexer:PlSqlLexer = PlSqlLexer(st)
        # Add your error listener to the lexer if required
        lexer.removeErrorListeners()
        lexer.addErrorListener( my_listener )
        
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        
        parser = PlSqlParser(stream)
        # Add your error listener to the _parser_ if required
        parser.removeErrorListeners()
        parser.addErrorListener( my_listener )
        ...
```